# Iterate Over Circular Area Of Hexagonal Grid?

Tags: algorithm

I am currently working with a hexagonal grid of cells which are indexed like this:

[image: Hexagonal Grid]

I am trying to find the simplest way to iterate over a circular area of this grid. For example, with `(3, 3)` as the center cell and a radius of one cell, I would want the loop to iterate over the cells `(3, 3), (4, 4), (4, 3), (4, 2), (3, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)` (in any order). Given the coordinate of the center cell and a radius (excluding the center cell), how would you construct a two-dimensional loop to iterate over each cell/coordinate?

Comment: Calculate the 6 corners of your (hexagonal) circle. If the center is [x, y] and the radius is r: Top left is [x-r/2-(y^r)&1, y+r], top right is [x+(r-1)/2-(y^r)&1, y+r], left is [x-r, y], right is [x+r, y], bottom left is [x-r/2-(y^r)&1, y-r], bottom right is [x+(r-1)/2-(y^r)&1, y-r]. Create 6 loops. For the diagonal sides you have to be careful, whether you start in an odd or even line. Either use an if clause or do as I did with ^ and & 1.

Comment: @Sebastian Thank you for your answer, but my question was: How would you construct the loop?

Comment: All 6 sides of the circle have length r and start and end at one of the corners I provided the coordinates for. The two horizontal sides are trivial, the diagonal sides are slightly different depending whether you start in an even or odd row.

Comment: Or you want to get the complete inside of the circle. Then Iterate from top to bottom (see coordinates) and calculate the left and the rightmost coordinate by connecting the corners diagonally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

### The basic idea:

Let's scan each row of the hexagon left-to-right.

### How to do it:

Let **R** be the "cell radius".

1. Start at the center and move left **R** cells. Call this cell "A". A's row has 2***R**-1 cells in it.
2. Now step one cell up/right. This cell begins a row with one less
   cell.
3. Repeat step 2 until you've stepped up/right **R** times.

This covers the top half. Now do the lower half with similar steps (stepping down/right starting from A, to find the beginning of each of those rows).

### Details

How do you step up/right?
The y coordinate increases by 1. The x coordinate increases by 1 only if y was odd.

How do you step down/right?
The y coordinate decreases by 1. The x coordinate increases by 1 only if y was odd.

Answer (score 2):

The choice of grid system is what makes this one complicated.  Because, for example, a step down and right might change your coordinates by `(1, -1)` or `(0, -1)` depending on which row you are in.

Therefore I would move to a different grid system, do the calculation there, then switch back to the grid system that you're showing.

Here is a demonstration of that in Python.

```
def loop (center, radius):
    if 0 == radius:
        yield center
    else:
        directions = [
            ( 1, -1),
            ( 0, -1),
            (-1,  0),
            (-1,  1),
            ( 0,  1),
            ( 1,  0),
        ]

        cell = list(to_normalized(center))

        cell[1] += radius

        for direction in directions:
            for i in range(radius):
                cell[0] += direction[0]
                cell[1] += direction[1]
                yield to_grid(cell)

def to_normalized (cell):
    return (cell[0] - (cell[1] // 2), cell[1])

def to_grid (cell):
    return (cell[0] + (cell[1] // 2), cell[1])

for cell in loop((3, 3), 2):
    print(cell)
```

Comment: Switching the coordinate system is what I did in the end, but when I asked this question I was interested in seeing a solution that works with the given coordinates.